# MacOS native hook listener Java

Tags: java, macos, hook, native, jnativehook

we currently have a `C#` DLL used by a java application with JNI in Windows.

It can get native listener hook from mouse, keyboard, get and replace text, get caret position and software info. I need the same for MacOS (High Sierra).

I made some research and i found `JNativeHook` which is very nice but missing some stuff i need like the caret position which is very important. Is this even possible on MacOS?

If so, What would be the best way to do it? I have a preference for `Objective-C` but i have no idea how this code could be used after in java.

Thanks